# VFP: 3d arrays?

Tags: arrays, foxpro, visual-foxpro, multidimensional-array

The following doesn't work... Can you do 3d arrays in foxpro?

```
DIMENSION sqlresults[10]
select list_code, count(donor) as ndine FROM cGift group by list_code INTO ARRAY sqlresults[1]
```

edit:
ah, a google search for "vfp multi-dimensional arrays" turned up something ("vfp 3d arrays" didn't)

Foxpro only supports 2d arrays. Guess i'll have to fake it with some substitution (&).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem with your code is that you included a dimension in the query. Try this instead:

```
select list_code, count(donor) as ndine 
  FROM cGift 
  group by list_code 
  INTO ARRAY sqlresults
```

That said, on the whole, you're better off putting query results into a cursor than an array.

Comment: my goal was to have an array of tables (a 3d array), not to just store the select's return in sqlresults.

Comment: As you discovered, VFP can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sqlresults[1] = sys(2015)
Select ... into cursor (sqlresults[1])
```

This way your array holds names of the cursors, and you can access their values like:

```
Select (sqlresults[1])
?fieldname
```

Or use eval or &